# Fullcalendar select wrong end date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, date, fullcalendar

I am using selectable function where when user select a date, it will shows the start and end date in a modal. but the the end date showed is extra one day from the actual selected date. for example, of i click on 1st march, the end date will showed 2nd march. here is my code:

```
select: function (start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
          var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
          $("#EndDate").val('');
          alert(end);

          if (view.name === "month") {
            $('#DateForm').modal('show');
            $("#EndDate").val(start.format('ddd, DD-MMM-YYYY, hh:mm a'));
          } else {
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the correct, documented behaviour. The documentation of the "end" property of an event states:

> The **exclusive** date/time an event ends. [...] It is the moment immediately *after* the event has ended.
>   For example, if the last full day of an event is **Thursday**, the
>   exclusive end of the event will be 00:00:00 on **Friday**!

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object for more.

---

P.S. the line `var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');` in your code above is redundant - you already have access to the view via the parameter of the same name in your callback. You can remove this line and the code will continue to work.

Comment: do you have any idea how to make minus the day so that it will show the correct date? I try to remove the line, but it didnt work

Comment: that _is_ the correct end date which fullCalendar has given to the event. If you report another date, it won't, technically be the correct date. However you can use momentJS's methods to manipulate the date for displaying it: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/.

Comment: P.S. you definitely can remove that extra line. The problem, I noticed, if that you've invented an extra "allDay" callback parameter for the "select" callback, so consequently the "view" parameter is not populated in your version. The value that should be in "view" is in "jsEvent". You can't just add extra variables to a callback which aren't going to be supplied by the caller. See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/308/ and see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback for the correct definition of the parameters in the callback

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this in this way**

```
      select: function (start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
      var endDate = new Date(end);
      beforeDay = new Date(endDate.getFullYear(),endDate.getMonth(),endDate.getDate() - 1);
      $("#EndDate").val(beforeDay.format('ddd, DD-MMM-YYYY, hh:mm a'));
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way

```js
select: function (info) {
            
  end_date = new Date(info.end);
  $('#form-add-shift input[name="end_date"]').val(end_date.toISOString().slice(0, 10));
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but after some struggle with the date as my project required it, I found a very simple and neat way of converting the date to the format I needed it:

```
document.getElementById("addEnd").value = moment(end).subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

A little clarification:\

- addEnd is my HTML input field type="date" that hods the end date of a selection\
- .substract)1, 'days') (could be add for a day increase) does the magic for me\
- .format(...) formats the date